# Extract a javascript variable with flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a little `flask` project and in my javascript script I have a variable which works as a counter.

When I receive a POST request I would like my `python` script to extract this counter variable.

I tried to set a `jinja2` variable by doing `{%set extractor_var = js_counter%}` but it seems to be impossible to use a javascript variable inside a `jinja2` template.

Can anyone lead me to another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't make sense! 
Flask/Jinja can't read from javascript vars.
However, (as you said it is a POST request) you could:

## Three ways:

- Passing (dynamically modifying DOM link or form action URL) counter var value to POST request URL, like:
  /path/postaction?counter=4;
- If it's a POST request from form you could modify form action (see
  above) or adding a input hidden to form;
- Setting a cookie and get it in the next request (I don't like this option);